# Seeder not working laravel 5.2

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, seeding

So consider the following err:

```
  [PDOException]                                                                                                 
  SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint  
  DETAIL:  Failing row contains (5, Sample Name xxx@gmail.com, xxxxxx, null, null, null).
```

This is the seeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class AdminUser extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name'      => 'Sample Name',
            'email'     => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
            'password'  => 'xxxxxx',
        ]);
    }
}
```

The user model:

```
class Users extends Model {
    protected $table        = 'users';
    protected $timestamps   = true;
    protected $fillable     = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
}
```

Whats going on? The migration, default from laravel install:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

**Did they miss something? Did I?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eloquent models automatically inserts timestamps for you, but the query builder doesn't. As the error message says, they can't be null. You have two options:

1. Add the timestamps manually:

   ```
   DB::table('users')->insert([
       'name'      => 'Sample Name',
       'email'     => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
       'password'  => 'xxxxxx',
       'updated_at' => new \Carbon\Carbon,
       'created_at' => new \Carbon\Carbon
   ]);
   ```
2. Or use your User model to seed the database, and it will handle adding the timestamps for you.

   ```
   User::create([
       'name'      => 'Sample Name',
       'email'     => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
       'password'  => 'xxxxxx'
   ]);
   ```